# Display ul li items in two columns with a scrolling vertical overflow

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'd like to display two columns of `li` objects within a `ul`, with a fixed height where the items scroll vertically.

I'm creating the columns of `li` objects using the css `columns` rule, but at the moment the result ignores the number of columns I specify, and the `overflow-y` rule, and overflows horizontally instead.

Does anyone know how to get the `ul` to scroll vertically with a 2 fixed columns instead?

**Note** - I need to keep all the `lis` within a single `ul` as they are being used as part of a `JQuery Sortable` control.

**Markup**

```
<ul class="twoColsVerticalScroll">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>    
  ... lots of lis ...
</ul>
```

**Css**

```
 .twoColsVerticalScroll {
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: red;
    -moz-columns: 2 100px;
    -webkit-columns: 2 100px;
    columns: 2 100px;
}
```

**Result**

https://jsfiddle.net/xh4kq0h5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your list in div with `overflow: scroll` and set its sizes. Then set width of columns to 50%; Don't forget to reset margins and paddings of `ul`.

**Update**

Add FF support.

```css
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
       -moz-column-count: 2;
            column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-width: 50%;
       -moz-column-width: 50%;
            column-width: 50%;   
}

div {
    width: 420px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="twoColsVerticalScroll">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ted I updated my answer - added prefixes for Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think percentages are valid values for the column-width property, but it's working fine now anyway. I think the main problem was my approach to the overflow. Thanks again!